# How to get android application to take priority with the indicator light

Tags: java, android

I am trying to learn more about the indicator lights and how to use them, so i am creating an app to blink the indicator light different colors when different notifications appear. The problem is that if a notification already is controlling the indicator light i cant do my own thing, is there anyway to block other applications from it or override them?

This is my code for the notification listener

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService
{
    private final String TAG = "NotificationListenerTestingTag";
    private NotificationManager notifMgr;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.v(TAG, "Service Created");

        // Get the Notification Manager
        notifMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification n) 
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Notification Posted: " + n.getPackageName());

        // Turn on indicator light
        Notification ledControll = new Notification();
        ledControll.ledARGB = Color.argb(255, 0, 255, 0);
        ledControll.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        ledControll.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;
        ledControll.ledOnMS = 200;
        ledControll.ledOffMS = 300;

        notifMgr.notify(n.hashCode(), ledControll);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification n) 
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Notification Removed: " + n.getPackageName());

        // Turn off indicator light
        notifMgr.cancel(n.hashCode());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am creating an app to blink the indicator light different colors when different notifications appear

That is unlikely to work well. For example, you cannot add an indicator light to hardware that lacks it, and you cannot filter your app to only be available to devices that have an indicator light.

> is there anyway to block other applications from it or override them?

No. You also cannot prevent the device from using the indicator light for other purposes, such as charging status.